# How do I get tor exit node information of a certain connection I made

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, tor

At some point today my email client warned about an smtp certificate change of self signed certs. I took a screenshot of the certificate fingerprints and refused the connection because it does not seem to make sense.

The server in question has a valid https certificate, but on their website nothing about their smtp cert, nor about it having changed.

Now if they answer me that they didn't change it, this is probably an ssl injection and I would like to send them details including which exit node did this.

It would also allow me to compare with tested exit nodes like this service: xqz3u5drneuzhaeo.onion/users/badtornodes/

I must have a default tor logging settup on linux. Where can I find which exit node I was connected to at a given time?

/var/log/tor/log seems to have only warnings and upwards in it...

Answer (score 0):

Tor does *not* log such information by default, since it would go directly against Tor's purpose of providing anonymity.

Your server's administrators, on the other hand, can easily determine the relevant exit node themselves, since after all it connected directly to the SMTP server – and most mail servers keep timestamped logs of incoming connections.

Comment: You 're right... Obviously they have them. Didn't think long enough... On the other hand, they probably have much more people connecting than I do, and I wouldn't mind to test for myself. Any easy way to have limited logging for tor like an hour and have the logrotating secure remove the logs? Maybe I can just up the loglevel, retry connecting to that server immediately and then wipe the logs myself...

Comment: You could (I think Vidalia even allows doing it without restarting Tor). But since 3 hours have passed already, I'm quite sure Tor has already forgot about that particular exit.